# Magento PayPal Pro Error #10471 & #10472

Tags: magento, paypal

I have the following problem. I am trying to get payments by PayPal Pro on my Magento store(Website Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) - method). Everything works normal if i try to pay by credit card, but if i select PayPal to pay(i mean to pay with money from my PayPal account not with credit card) i get the following error:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. ReturnURL is invalid (#10471: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details). CancelURL is invalid (#10472: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).
```

If i select on Magento admin standard PayPal(Website Payments Standard, to be more exactly) i can pay with my PayPal account, but this method don't have credit card payment method.

I use Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the table in database core_config_data the path next to web/unsecure/base_url is like http://yoursite.com:/ therefore it is generating problem change it to http://yoursite.com/   all of the paypal problem will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved removing underscores from the domain name!

Changing from this:

`http://magento_1_9.dev/`

to this:

`http://magento-1-9.dev/`

solved the issue.

I found this solution here: https://forum.foxycart.com/discussion/2354/returnurl-is-invalid-error-10471-paypal-express